# Syntax error in WebStorm when write `@import "path/to/css" layer(xyz)`

Tags: css, intellij-idea, sass, webstorm

I'm trying to use the new syntax of the CSS layer in my `.scss` files into my personal project :

```css
@import "@animxyz/core" layer(xyz-animation);
```

That syntax works fine in the browser but it looks like WebStorm does not recognize it as a legit syntax. It's kind of annoying.

Same thing with `@property` as the next syntax work but shows syntax error:

```scss
@property --deg {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0deg;
}
```

Any direction on how to solve those would be appreciated.

I tried to look if there is some update for the internal Sass/CSS plugin, but there is none.

Answer (score 1):

CSS `@layer` syntax is not yet supported, please follow [WEB-55075](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55075/Support-CSS-layer) for updates